# How can I copy specific data using batch file?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

This is the data.

```
mean MP2  rms         :  0.287070 m
```

I just want to `0.287070`

How can I do this?

I have tried many commands, but they have all failed.

Comment: I think your caps lock is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is 6 fields separated by spaces and no weird characters, you can use this:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims= " %%a in ("data.txt") do (
    echo %%e
)
```

In the loop, each field gets a letter from `%%a` through `%%f`.  `%%e` is the data you want.  Example:

```
C:\batch>get_data.cmd
0.287070
0.387070
0.487070
0.587070
```

Answer (score -1):

If all your data has exactly a pattern of 1 digit, 1 dot, 6 digits you can sed :

```
sed -r 's/.*([0-9]\.[0-9]{6}).*/\1/' file
```

If you want only this pattern in the lines containig "mean MP2  rms" :

```
sed -r 's/mean MP2  rms.*([0-9]\.[0-9]{6}).*/\1/' file
```

Comment: Just to expound upon your answer. The `sed` command is only Unix/Linux systems.
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: To use a Windows command similar to `sed` see `findstr`.  http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Comment: @DavidRuhmann - FINDSTR cannot extract matching text from a line. It can only print the entire line that contains the match.

Comment: @dbenham  That is true, but a simple `for` can be added to do that part. `for /f "usebackq tokens=5" %%A in (``find or findstr``) do echo.%%A`

Comment: There are plenty of sed implementations for Windows.  E.g., http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: how can i save the all data in a .txt file, it just save the last data, not all. and from the result using that command, all data with same patter are come out, i just want the 'mean MP2  rms' value only. how can i specific it.

Comment: You can specify the regex to match only the lines containig "mean MP2  rms", i have edited my answer to show you how.